# Manchester Library Won't Compile for Attiny85

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, compile, attiny, rf

I am creating a wireless sensor using an Attiny85.  I want to send the data to an arduino uno, so I purchased the 315mhz rf link kit from spark fun.  Since the Attiny85 does not have a TX I decided to use the Manchester library however it won't compile on the Attiny85.

I followed the steps from this blog :
http://mchr3k-arduino.blogspot.mx/2012/01/wireless-sensor-node-part-2.html?showComment=1338749638806#c853067277980266192

Here is the code I am using:

```
    #include <WProgram.h> //otherwise it says it can't find Arduino.h
    #include <Manchester.h> //include the library to comunicate
    #define TxPin 2 //the pin that is used to send data

 int sensorPin = 4;
 int ledPin = 3;
 int count = 50;

 void setup(){
  pinMode (ledPin, OUTPUT);
  man.workAround1MhzTinyCore(); //add this in order for transmitter to work with 1Mhz Attiny85/84
  man.setupTransmit(TxPin, MAN_1200); //set transimt pin
}

void loop(){
  if (count == 50){
   digitalWrite (ledPin, HIGH);
   count = 0;
   }
   int data = analogRead(sensorPin);
   man.transmit(data); //transmits and reads the data
   delay (100);
   count ++;
 }
```

Here is the error message:

```
/Users/joelsimonoff/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MANCHESTER/Manchester.cpp: In function 'void MANRX_SetupReceive(uint8_t)':
/Users/joelsimonoff/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MANCHESTER/Manchester.cpp:366: error: 'TCCR2A' was not declared in this scope
/Users/joelsimonoff/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MANCHESTER/Manchester.cpp:366: error: 'WGM21' was not declared in this scope
/Users/joelsimonoff/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MANCHESTER/Manchester.cpp:368: error: 'TCCR2B' was not declared in this scope
/Users/joelsimonoff/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MANCHESTER/Manchester.cpp:368: error: 'CS21' was not declared in this scope
/Users/joelsimonoff/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MANCHESTER/Manchester.cpp:369: error: 'OCR2A' was not declared in this scope
/Users/joelsimonoff/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MANCHESTER/Manchester.cpp:379: error: 'TIMSK2' was not declared in this scope
/Users/joelsimonoff/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MANCHESTER/Manchester.cpp:379: error: 'OCIE2A' was not declared in this scope
/Users/joelsimonoff/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MANCHESTER/Manchester.cpp:380: error: 'TCNT2' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Which package are you using for ATtinyX5 Arduino support?

Comment: I tried the one from the blog I referenced but after google searching I found that the MIT High Low Tech Group had one so I tried that one as well.  The one from MIT High Low Tech is from this page http://highlowtech.org/?p=1695

Comment: I performed all of Joel's and Ignacio's suggestions concerning using the arduino-tiny library instead of the attiny master from the MIT high low tech group page. I've finally got the ATTINY85 boards to show up in my board menu, but I'm still getting the error "man not declared in scope" with the above code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you import the manchester library into the Arduino IDE? or Place it in the libraries folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[attiny](https://github.com/damellis/attiny/) is missing an option required to allow the Manchester library to function properly on ATtinyX5 devices, specifically definition of `__AVR_ATtinyX5__` when a device is selected. In fact, it's missing quite a few things.

The package I use for ATtinyX5 support is [arduino-tiny](http://code.google.com/p/arduino-tiny/). I have verified that it defines that symbol properly. I recommend that you dump your current support package and install arduino-tiny instead.

Comment: I downloaded the arduino-tiny-0150-0020.zip.  Unzipped the file then dragged the folder named tiny into the hardware folder I created inside the arduino folder.  However when I went to the ide I searched under boards and the Attiny series of boards did not show up.

Comment: What is the correct way to add the package to the ice?

Comment: Which version of the IDE are you running?

Comment: Arduino1.0.5 on mac osx 10.9.2

Comment: Then you'll need to download the support package for 1.0.x instead of the one for 1.5.x.

Comment: I just downloaded the package  arduino-tiny-0100-0018.zip  and inserted the folder tiny into my hardware folder and the boards are still not loading.

Comment: this is the file path /Users/joelsimonoff/Documents/Arduino/hardware/tiny

Comment: I renamed the file from tiny to attiny and the file prospective boards to boards and the boards now show up in the ide

Comment: the file just compiled successfully I am gonna try to hook it up to the chip

Answer (score 4):

Having struggled through this myself, I can confirm that Joel's solution works.

There are quite a lot of posts around that suggests that you can't get the Manchester to work with Arduino1.0x and you need 0020. But you can.

The key is to use the arduino-tiny from the link above, put the tiny folder which you get from there in /hardware and then rename it to attiny and “prospective boards” to boards.

I realise that this doesn’t say any more than Joel already has, but there is so much conflicting and contradictory information around I thought it would be worth adding in my experience

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem using this lib with a 8 MHz Trinket, but managed to solve it by adding `#define __AVR_ATtinyX5__` to the file hardware/attiny/variants/tiny8/pins_arduino.h. I'm using the Adafruit support package for ATtiny. Perhaps a bit of a hack, but I can still build for the UNO, by selecting board in Arduino IDE 1.0.5.